# ajax autocomplete from array

Tags: php, ajax, autocomplete

i'm trying to create a simple autocomplete textbox that takes the suggestions from an array.the code i'm using(based on [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?gl=GR&v=OISdZ4HeNIM))  is :

call.php

```
<?php
$list = array(
    "Autocomplete",
    "Metapher",
    "Metatag");

for($i=0; $i<count($list); $i++){
    if(strpos($list[$i], $_GET['str']) !== FALSE && strlen($_GET['str']) >= 2){
        echo str_ireplace($_GET['str'], '<b style="color:   red;">'.$_GET['str'].'</b>', $list[$i]) . '<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX - 03</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest;

            function t(){           
                ajax.open("GET", "call.php?str=" + document.getElementById("test").value, false);
                ajax.send();

        ajax.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
          if (ajax.readyState==4 && ajax.status==200)
          {
                document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
          }
       }
    }

        </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="border: 3px; border-style: solid; font-size: 42pt; border-radius: 7px;">
    Text
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <input id="test" type="text" onkeyup="javascript:t()">
</body>
</html>
```

but nothing comes up at the suggestion box.I can't find any syntax errors so i suppose there is something wrong with the logic?

**UPDATE**:
after the advice from PLB and FAngel i added the onreadystatechange and the checks.However it still doesn;t work properly.Actually i just found that if you type a compination of letters that are inside one of the 3 words the suggestions come up properly.It just doesnt work if you type the starting letters of a word.For example if i give "com" as input the word Autocomplete comes up.However if i give "Aut" then nothing.So i guess the actual problem is here:

```
if(**strpos($list[$i], $_GET['str']) !== FALSE** && strlen($_GET['str']) >= 2)
```

From what i read here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php the problem could be the use of != but i use !== as i should.Any thoughts?

Comment: First of all, you have to check your php manually from browser. Secondly, in your js function you should check states: `ajax.onreadystatechanged = function() { alert("State: " + ajax.readyState + "; Status: " + ajax.status); }` When State is 4 and status 200 everything is ok and you can show data. Otherwise something went wrong (to check exactly what use google).

Comment: Nothing is wrong. What are you trying to check? See my answer.

Comment: @PLB you are right,the checks should be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing that your request is asynchronous. So when you run this line: `document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;`, request is not done yet. Take a look at [this](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call) . `onreadystatechange` is what you need. Or make that call synchronous

Comment: Thanks for the advice,i added what you suggested.However seems after all the problem is at the statement that uses strpos.Ckeck my update.

Comment: What is your input for auto exactly? I've tried it on my PC - works fine if A in "Aut" is upper case, but lower case "aut" returns nothing. Which is loggical since `strpos` is case sensitive and you may need to use `stripos` instead

Comment: Yes you are right,after adding the onreadystatechange and the state checks i only tried it with lower a.It works as expected now.Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can also work it like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/qz29K/

All you need is you just replace the json array with php jsonencoding like this

```
$list = array(
"Autocomplete",
"Metapher",
"Metatag");

<script>
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($list) ?>
</script>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: i think this is a nice way to do what i intended.However i'd like to ask because my next step woulb using a separate file,is it possible to load the array from a file if i use this way?

Comment: yes you can do anything like in the case you want to add it in  separate file while you are loading that file you can call the same function all you have to do is only you have to just load new array and assign in to a a json encoded variable...

Answer (score 1):

It totally WORKS!

I tried it.

I had input : Met

and it gave me Metaphor and one more word.

However, for advanced usage. Check this out, you gonna love it.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: thanks for taking the time to try this,but i really must insist that it is not working.Not properly at least,since after sometime i realised that some compinations have some results because they are at the middle of the words and then suggestions come up.I updated my question to describe this. In any case thank very much for your link it was really helpful!