# How to fit JSON data source to Jquery Autocomplete widget?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I want to use a Jquery UI- Autocomplete. 
Here is the method to use Autocomplete.

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Here the array "availableTags" is defined. But I want to generate the autocomplete from a data source which is a server-side script which returns JSON data.can anyone help me to fit that data source to autocomplete??

Im using MVC architecture (Codeigniter) and using following method in controller to return the JSON data,

```
function supcode(){     
    $dataarray="";
    $data=$this->Inventorymodel->supcode();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

And I am fetching the data in model using following function,

```
function supcode(){
    $finresult="";
    $this->db->select('name');
    $query = $this->db->get('supplier');
    $result=$query->result_array();

    foreach($result as $row){
        $finresult[]=array(
            'name' => $row['name']
        );
    }
    return $finresult;
}
```

And here is the URL to the function supcode in controller,
"index.php/inventory/supcode"

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: see my answer on this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072922/ajax-autocomplete-from-array/12074562#12074562

Let me know if any help needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
source: 'index.php/inventory/supcode',
```

and replace

```
    foreach($result as $row){
       $finresult[]=array(
        'name' => $row['name']
       );
    }
```

to

```
foreach($result as $row){
   $finresult[]=$row['name'];
}
```

Comment: check what return server in firebug  and in supcode replace    $finresult[]=$row['name']

Comment: [{"name":"abcd"},{"name":"efgh"},{"name":"klmn"}]   this is the respons im getting in firebug.....when i type a letter in textbox a blank list appears...

Comment: but i have a problem now....when i type "a" all values which doesnt contains the leter "a" are listed in the list...

Comment: sorry... i don`t understand u

Comment: I mean the data is not filtering.When I type a letter in textbox the values are listed in the autocomplete list without filtering. check the screenshot here. http://www.4shared.com/photo/I9rqlh8w/Capture_2.html?

Answer (score 1):

Don't wrap the name with array, just do:

```
foreach($result as $row){
    $finresult[]= $row['name'];
}
```

And in the javascript side, set the `source` with the url:

```
source: 'index.php/inventory/supcode',
```

Comment: Now I have a problem. Data is not filtering.when I type a letter in textbox, all the values are listed in the autocomplete list without filtering. check the screenshot here. 4shared.com/photo/I9rqlh8w/Capture_2.html?

Comment: @BasimSherif You need to do the filtering in the server side.